# C++ how to figure if a mutex is being disproportionately hogged by a single thread while blocking other threads

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, performance, mutex

I want to analyze how a particular mutex is being time-shared between two threads. I am trying to debug an issue where I feel one of the threads is locking/unlocking very rapidly, which might be starving the other thread from acquiring that lock.

Details:

Thread T1:

```
while (1) {
  //...non-blocking trivial work

  lock();
  //do little work on a shared DS1
  unlock();

  //...blocking work
}
```

Thread T2:

```
run() {
   //...does a bunch of blocking work

   lock();
   // update shared DS1
   unlock();

   return;
}
```

Thread T1 is dispatcher thread doing a tight-loop checking very frequently if the shared DS1 has been updated.
Thread T2 does a lot more work and finally updates the shared DS1.

I feel T1 is hogging the lock significantly while starving T2 from acquiring the lock quick enough.

I want to measure how much time a particular thread holds on to that lock. How much time is spent by T2 in contention for the lock.

Comment: *Are there any tools/ways to measure this?* Sorry, this part of your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. As the rest of your question seems okay, I have simply edited this part out of your question.

Comment: Can you explain why you "feel one of the threads is locking/unlocking very rapidly, which might be starving the other thread from acquiring that lock"?   What evidence is there to support your feeling?   Generally speaking, however, unless the threads have different priority  (e.g. there is a priority inversion in play)  one thread unlocking will allow another thread which is attempting to lock to actually acquire that lock.    If T2 attempts to lock the mutex infrequently, and T1 attempts to lock it frequently, it is only natural that T2 will lock it much less often than T1.

Answer (score 2):

It should be pretty straightforward to measure how much time T2 spends waiting for the lock() call to return:

```
// Thread T2
run() {
   //...does a bunch of blocking work

   // use whatever get-current-time API you like here
   const uint64_t t1 = get_current_time_in_microseconds();  
   lock();
   const uint64_t t2 = get_current_time_in_microseconds();

   const uint64_t time_spent_waiting_for_lock = (t2-t1);

   // Add code here to calculate minimum/average/max values 
   // of time_spent_waiting_for_lock over the course of your test

   // update shared DS1
   unlock();

   return;
}
```

Comment: But how does this say whether thread T2 is using the lock more than T1? I want to know the time-splice of the lock between the two threads.

Comment: Assuming there are only two threads competing for the lock, then it's safe to assume that if T2 is waiting for the lock, it must be because T1 currently has ownership of the lock (otherwise T2's `lock()` call would return immediately).  If you want to also measure how long T1 takes to acquire the lock, or the amount of time that T1 keeps the lock acquired, the same technique can be used for that as well.